# How to preserve partial matches while modifying others with awk?

Tags: regex, awk

How to preserve partial matches while modifying others with awk ?

Example: from "method ( arg", I would like to get "method(arg".

```
>> echo "method ( arg" | awk '{line = $0; gensub("[a-zA-Z]+ *\( *[a-zA-Z]+", "\1\2\3", "g", line); print line;}'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /[a-zA-Z]+ *( *[a-zA-Z]+/

>> echo "method ( arg" | awk '{line = $0; gensub("[a-zA-Z]+ *[(] *[a-zA-Z]+", "\1\2\3", "g", line); print line;}'
method ( arg
```

**EDIT**

For the record:

```
>> echo "method ( arg" | awk '{line = $0; print gensub(/([a-zA-Z]+) *\( *([a-zA-Z]+)/, "\\1(\\2", "g", line)}'
method(arg

>> echo "method ( arg" | awk '{line = $0; print gensub(/([[:alpha:]]+) *\( *([[:alpha:]]+)/, "\\1(\\2", "g", line)}'
method(arg
```

Comment: Your sample input should really be a sting that shows `method ( arg` surrounded by other text that you do NOT want the spaces to be modified in. As written you could just do `tr -d ' '` and produce the expected output from the sample input so your currently posted sample input/output does not provide an adequate test of whether or not a potential solution script does what's required.

Comment: What's the `EDIT For the record` addition intended to tell us? Again, `echo "method ( arg"` piped to `tr -d ' '` or `awk '{gsub(/ /,"")}1'` or `sed 's/ //g'` or ... would produce the same output given that input so what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to solve this problem, but here is a solution similar to your initial attempt with `awk`:

```
echo "method ( arg" |
  gawk '{line = $0; print gensub("([a-zA-Z]+) *(\\() *([a-zA-Z]+)", "\\1\\2\\3", "g", line)}'
```

There were a number of issues with your original code:

- `\(` did not work because you need to *double-escape* it -- since the backslash itself needs escaping too.
- `\1`, `\2` and `\3` were also not working, for the same reason.
- `gawk` returns a new string; it does not modify the original variable. So you either need to print this directly (like I did), or same the result to a new variable.
- *You weren't actually using any capture groups* - so the `\1`, `\2` and `\3` were not matching anything!! I added these above. Since the whitespace is outside of the capture groups, this solves your original problem.

Here is a much simpler solution, using `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
echo "method ( arg" | sed -E "s/([a-zA-Z]+) *(\() *([a-zA-Z]+)/\1\2\3/g"
```

The principle is the same, but there's much less confusion around what needs escaping (or double-escaping)!

Comment: Thanks. So you need to group [a-zA-Z]+ with () : I understanding this even if I am not sure know why this is necessary. And you need to replace \ by \\: this is the main point I still can't really explain...  But it works !

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. I understand now !

Comment: What did you expect `\1` to match? It's the result of capture group number 1 -- i.e. The first pair of brackets. As for the double-backslash, this is a problem that occurs in many languages: Since you effectively wrote a *nested* function, the backlash itself needed escaping. Sometimes, in extreme situations, code can even need 4 backslash characters to deal with the repeated string evaluation.

Comment: I didn't get that \n matched the n-th () !... I was trying to understand how all this work

Comment: wrt `\\(` and `the backslash itself needs escaping` - no, the expression needs to be within regexp deimiters instead of string delimiters. You only need to escape the backslash because you're using string delimiters in a regexp context and so the string needs to be converted to a regexp (using up one escape) before the regexp can actually be applied (using the second escape). The right solution is to just use regexp delimiters `/.../`, not string delimiters `"..."`. Also you should use character classes `[[:alpha:]]`, not character ranges `[a-zA-Z]` for portability across locales.

Comment: So use `gensub(/([[:alpha:]]+) *(\() *([[:alpha:]]+)/, "\\1\\2\\3", "g", line)` instead of `gensub("([a-zA-Z]+) *(\\() *([a-zA-Z]+)", "\\1\\2\\3", "g", line)`.  Also in the sed script (or any other script) - always enclose everything entirely in single quotes `'...'` unless you **need** to use double quotes, e.g. to let a shell variable expand, and then use it cautiously and only around the part of the script that needs to be opened up to the shell, e.g. `sed 's/foo'"$var"'bar/other/'`. So your echo+sed should be `echo 'method ( arg' | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]+) *(\() *([a-zA-Z]+)/\1\2\3/g'`

Answer (score 0):

See my comments under [@TomLord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660616/1745001) for what the issues are with your script and Toms but here's how to really do what you're attempting using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() + gensub():

```
$ echo 'here is method ( argi etc' |
gawk 'match($0,/(.*)(\w+\s*\(\s*\w+)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] gensub(/\s+/,"","g",a[2]) a[3]} 1'
here is method(argi etc
```

I also used `\w` for "word constituent characters" as I expect the tokens you're matching on can probably include `_`s as they seem to be representing function/method and argument names so using `[[:alpha:]]` or `[a-zA-Z]` isn't adequate (`\w` is shorthand for `[[:alpha:]_]`) and I used `\s` which is shorthand for `[[:space:]]` rather than restricting the spaces between tokens to just blank characters. `\w` and `\s` are also gawk-specific.

If you didn't have gawk (which you do) then the solution would be the same approach but more code:

```
$ echo 'here is method ( argi etc' |
awk 'match($0,/[[:alpha:]_]+[[:space:]]*\([[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]_]+/) {
    tgt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",tgt)
    $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
} 1'
here is method(argi etc
```

Note that the above works on the target string `method ( argi` in-context wherever it appears on a line and doesn't require it to be on a line of it's own as your/Toms scripts required and that the removal of spaces is decoupled from the identification of the target string and so no longer relies on your target string having exactly 3 space-separated fields to function so if you had to identify a target string with 20 fields you'd just change the regexp used in match(), you would not have to change the code that performs the space removal unlike in your original script where space removal relies on exactly 3 backreferences.